AirflowException("Waiter error: max attempts reached")
I am using AWS MWAA with airflow version apache-airflow 2.8.1.
I am getting this error:
 File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/utils/waiter_with_logging.py", line 82, in wait raise AirflowException("Waiter error: max attempts reached") airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Waiter error: max attempts reached

How can I fix this?
I am calling an EMR serverless job from airflow. The job is a long running one and has to be synchronous.
